# Laravel - how to redirect Integrity constraint violation: 1451 to failed notifications?

Tags: laravel

I have a table named merks and it's id is a foreign key in another table named barangs.
so when I tried to delete a data in table merks but the data have been used in table barangs, it give me this

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventorylite`.`barangs`, CONSTRAINT `barangs_merk_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`merk_id`) REFERENCES `merks` (`id`))

but I want to give user a notifications like,

> "Cant delete this item because its already used"

and redirect them into index view,

this is my destroy controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $delete = Merk::destroy($id);
        if($delete){
            return redirect()->route('merk.index')->with('success', 'Merk barang berhasil dihapus');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('merk.index')->with('failed', 'Merk barang gagal dihapus');
        }
    }
```

but it's not working, is there any solutions for this?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have any relationships set up? You could just query them and not perform the delete if they are in use. `if (Merk::find($id)->relationship()->exists()) { return redirect('merk.index')->with('failed', 'In use'); }` (or something similar)

Comment: @TimLewis yes I Have
in Barangs Model 

protected $with = ['merk'];

public function merk()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merk::class);
    }

and I try your code but it gave me "Call to undefined method App\Models\Merk::relationship()"

but I already try Mad an answer and its'working

Comment: Obviously you don't have a `relationship()` method... The expectation of that comment was to replace `->relationship()` with an _actual_ method, like `Merk::find($id)->barangs()->exist()`... ‍♂️

Comment: ah, sorry for that, newbie here, but it's okay now, problem is solved now, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try and catch for it. Example code is here

```
public function destroy($id)
{
try {
    $delete = Merk::destroy($id);
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
return redirect()->route('merk.index')->with('failed', 'Merk barang gagal dihapus');
}
return redirect()->route('merk.index')->with('success', 'Merk barang berhasil dihapus');
  
}
```

Comment: thx a lot, its' working :D